# Which is the good way to update object in EF6

Tags: entity-framework

I have searched and find 2 way to update object in EF

```
var attachedEntity = _context.EntityClasses.Local.First(t => t.Id == entity.Id);
  //We have it in the context, need to update.
  if (attachedEntity != null)
  {
     var attachedEntry = _context.Entry(attachedEntity);
     attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
  }
  else
  {
  ////If it's not found locally, we can attach it by setting state to modified.
  ////This would result in a SQL update statement for all fields
  ////when SaveChanges is called. 
  var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
  entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
  }
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

And other way is seem more easy

```
 var entity = _context.EntityClasses.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == entity.Id);
    _context.Entry(entity ).EntityState.Modified
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

What is best way to update object? 
NOTE: the performence is importance with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. _context.EntityClasses.Local.First(t => t.Id == entity.Id)
   => means that you want to double check the entity on local (the latest loading from DB) and it is not send to DB to find the record so the performance is faster.
2. _context.EntityClasses.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == entity.Id): This command is look up the entity in DB. That means EF creates the query and look up in DB.

The below link is the difference of between Entity.Local.Find & Entity.Find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx

Hope it helps!